# "Tim seems can't understand it"

Tags: complementation

Is it grammatically wrong to say

> Tim seems can't understand it.

What should I say to make it make sense, while retaining the meaning?

Comment: It is not grammatically correct.  I am not sure what you mean to say.  Perhaps if you add some context around the sentence, the meaning will be clearer and we can help with understanding how to say it.

Comment: Not detailed. Please say what you exactly want to say. Then you'll definitely get answers from better people than me.

Comment: As noted, it's unclear what you're asking. For example, *Tim can't seem to understand it* and *It seems Tim can't understand it* would be grammatical, but they mean different things, and may not mean the same thing you are trying to express.

Comment: @choster: what differences are between the meanings of the two sentences?

Comment: *Tim seems can't understand it* doesn't have a specific meaning, so a grammatical sentence with the intended meaning can't be formulated without a bit of guesswork.  My best guess would be what IͶΔ wrote in his answer, but I'm afraid it is still just a guess.

Answer (score 7):

You edited your post and changed the subject to "Tim". Yet there's no difference in the answer: The sentence is not grammatically correct.

> Tim seems can't understand it.

Two verbs in one sentence; none are auxiliary. Let's try to correct the sentence now.

If you want the order of the words to be maintained, I would recommend correcting the sentence by making a second clause.

First, Tim is not "seeming"! It's just that probably he can't understand the topic. So the subject of the verb "seems" mustn't be Tim. The best replacement is "it":

> It seems...

Tim can't understand the topic, maybe. So the rest of the sentence would be in a way that we get:

> It seems Tim can't understand it.

For clarification, I suggest that you add a "that" or a "like", as following:

> It seems that/like Tim can't understand it.

Our sentence is ready to be served. :)

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is indeed grammatically incorrect. As written, the subject of "Somebody" would agree with the predicate of "can't do something?" without issue. But the "seems" is a predicate that is missing a subject. So removing *seems* would fix the (rather vague, but now grammatically correct) sentence.

> Somebody can't do something?

But since you've included the seems, I'm going to assume you want that to be part of the sentence. So in order for that to be added to the sentence, we need to use a different word in the current context.

> Somebody *apparently* can't do something?

The word **apparently** takes the place of an entire clause, in this case the clause "seems that they" which would also be proper grammar in the context of the sentence.

> Somebody *seems that they* can't do something?

Hopefully, one of the two latter examples will be what you're looking for.